# Find all integers between m and n whose sum of squared divisors is itself a square

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm

### Problem Question

Divisors of 42 are : 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 14, 21, 42. These divisors squared are: 1, 4, 9, 36, 49, 196, 441, 1764. The sum of the squared divisors is 2500 which is 50 * 50, a square!

Given two integers m, n (1 <= m <= n) we want to find all integers between m and n whose sum of squared divisors is itself a square. 42 is such a number.

The result will be an array of arrays, each subarray having two elements, first the number whose squared divisors is a square and then the sum of the squared divisors.

## Code below

How can I make this specific program run faster? My current code times out after n > 9999.

```
#returns the divisors of each number in an array of arrays

r = (m..n).to_a.map { |z| (1..z).select { |x| z % x == 0} }

#this finds all integers between m and n whose sum of squared divisors is itself a square

squarenumbers = r.map { |x| x.map { |c| c**2 }.inject(:+) }.select { |x| Math.sqrt(x) % 1 == 0 }

#returns an array of booleans. 

booleans = r.map { |x| x.map { |c| c**2 }.inject(:+) }.map { |x| Math.sqrt(x) % 1 == 0 }

#returns the index of each of the true values in booleans as an array

indexer = booleans.map.with_index{|x, i| i if x == true }.compact

#returns the numbers whose squared divisors is a square in an array

unsqr = indexer.map { |x| (m..n).to_a[x] }

#merges the two arrays together, element for element and creates an array of arrays

unsqr.zip(squarenumbers) 

# for m = 1 and n = 1000 the result would be

# [[1, 1], [42, 2500], [246, 84100], [287, 84100], [728, 722500]]
```

Comment: Could you please format your question better?

Comment: Sorry. I just updated my question.

Comment: Can http://codereview.stackexchange.com help?

Comment: I will try my question there. thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Brute-force calculatioins of factors**

You begin by calculating:

```
m, n = 40, 42
r = (m..n).to_a.map { |z| (1..z).select { |x| z % x == 0} }
  #=> [[1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 20, 40], [1, 41], [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 14, 21, 42]]
```

That's OK, but you don't need `.to_a`:

```
r = (m..n).map { |z| (1..z).select { |x| z % x == 0} }
  #=> [[1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 20, 40], [1, 41], [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 14, 21, 42]]
```

This avoids an extra step, which is the creation of the temporary array<sup>1,2</sup>:

```
(m..n).to_a #=> [40, 41, 42]
```

**Structure of a solution**

Let's work backwards to come up with our code. First, concentrate on determining, for any given number `q`, if the sum of squares of the factors of `q` is itself a perfect square. Suppose we construct a method `magic_number?` which takes `q` as its only argument and returns `true` if `q` satisfies the required property and `false` otherwise. Then we will compute:

```
(m..n).select { |q| magic_number?(q) }
```

to return an array of all numbers between `m` and `n` that satisfy the property. `magic_number?` can be written like this:

```
def magic_number?(q)
  return true if q == 1
  s = sum_of_squared_factors(q)
  s == Math.sqrt(s).round**2
end
```

**Calculating sum of squared factors**

So now we are left with writing the method `sum_of_squared_factors`. We can use your code to obtain the factors:

```
def factors(q)
  (1..q).select { |x| q % x == 0 }
end

factors(40) #=> [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 20, 40] 
factors(41) #=> [1, 41] 
factors(42) #=> [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 14, 21, 42]
```

and then write:

```
def sum_of_squared_factors(q)
  factors(q).reduce(0) { |t,i| t + i*i }
end

sum_of_squared_factors(40) #=> 2210 
sum_of_squared_factors(41) #=> 1682 
sum_of_squared_factors(42) #=> 2500
```

**Speeding the calculation of factors**

There's something more we can do to speed up the calculation of factors. If `f` is a factor of `n`, `f` and `n/f`, are both factors of `n`. (For example, since `3` is a factor of `42`, so is `42/3 #=> 14`). We therefore need only obtain the smaller of each pair.

There is one exception to this rule. If `n` is a perfect square and `f == n**0.5`, then `f = n/f`, so we only include `f` among the factors of `n` (not `n/f` as well).

If turns out that if `f` is the smaller of the pair, `f <=(n**0.5).round`<sup>3</sup>. We therefore need only check to see which of the numbers `(1..(n**0.5).round)` are factors and include their complements (unless `n` is a perfect square, in which case we do not double-count `(n**0.5).round`):

```
q = 42
arr = (1..Math.sqrt(q).round).select { |x| q % x == 0 }
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 6] 
arr = arr.flat_map { |n| [n, q/n] }
  #=> [1, 42, 2, 21, 3, 14, 6, 7] 
arr.pop if a[-2] == a[-1]
arr
  #=> [1, 42, 2, 21, 3, 14, 6, 7]

q = 36
arr = (1..Math.sqrt(q).round).select { |x| q % x == 0 }
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6] 
arr = arr.flat_map { |n| [n, q/n] }
  #=> [1, 36, 2, 18, 3, 12, 4, 9, 6, 6] 
arr.pop if a[-2] == a[-1]
  #=> 6 
arr
  #=> [1, 36, 2, 18, 3, 12, 4, 9, 6]
```

so we can write:

```
def factors(q)
  arr = (1..Math.sqrt(q)).select { |x| q % x == 0 }
  arr = arr.flat_map { |n| [n, q/n] }
  arr.pop if arr[-2] == arr[-1]
  arr
end
```

Substituting out `arr` ("chaining" expressions), we obtain a typical Ruby expression:

```
def factors(q)
  (1..Math.sqrt(q)).select { |x| q % x == 0 }.
    flat_map { |n| [n, q/n] }.
    tap { |a| a.pop if a[-2] == a[-1] }
end

factors(42)
  #=> [1, 42, 2, 21, 3, 14, 6, 7] 
factors(36)
  #=> [1, 36, 2, 18, 3, 12, 4, 9, 6]
```

See [Enumerable#flat_map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) and [Object#tap](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-tap). (There's no need for this array to be sorted. In applications where it needs to be sorted, just tack `.sort` onto the end of `flat_map`s block.)

**Wrapping up**

In sum, we are left with the following:

```
def magic_number?(q)
  return true if q == 1
  s = sum_of_squared_factors(q)
  s == Math.sqrt(s).round**2
end

def sum_of_squared_factors(q)
  factors(q).reduce(0) { |t,i| t + i*i }
end

def factors(q)
  (1..Math.sqrt(q)).select { |x| q % x == 0 }.
    flat_map { |n| [n, q/n] }.
    tap { |a| a.pop if a[-2] == a[-1] }
end

m, n = 1, 1000
(m..n).select { |q| magic_number?(q) }
  #=> `[1, 42, 246, 287, 728]
```

This calculation was completed in a blink of an eye.

**Compute primes to further speed calculation of factors**

Lastly, let me describe an even faster way to compute the factors of a number, using the method [Prime::prime_division](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html#method-i-prime_division). That method decomposes any number into its prime components. Consider, for example, `n = 360`.

```
require 'prime'

Prime.prime_division(360)
  #=> [[2, 3], [3, 2], [5, 1]]
```

This tells us that:

```
360 == 2**3 * 3**2 * 5**1
  #=> true
```

It also tells us that every factor of `360` is the product of between `0` and `3` `2`'s, multiplied by between `0` and `2` `3`'s, multiplied by `0` or `1` `5`'s. Therefore:

```
 def factors(n)
   Prime.prime_division(n).reduce([1]) do |a,(prime,pow)|
     a.product((0..pow).map { |po| prime**po }).map { |x,y| x*y }
   end
 end

 a = factors(360).sort
   #=> [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  8,  9, 10,  12,  15,  18,
   #    20, 24, 30, 36, 40, 45, 60, 72, 90, 120, 180, 360]
```

We can check that:

```
 a == (1..360).select { |n| (360 % n).zero? }
   #=> true
```

One other check:

```
 factors(40).sort
   #=> [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 20, 40]
```

<sup>1. You could instead write that `[*m..n] #=> [40, 41, 42]`.</sup>
<sup>2. Why is it not necessary to convert the range to an array? [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map), being an instance method of the module `Enumerable`, is available for use by every class that `include`s `Enumerable`. `Array` is one, but `(m..n).class #=> Range` is another. (See the second paragraph at [Range](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html)).</sup>
<sup>3. Suppose `f` is smaller than `n/f` and `f > n**0.5`, then `n/f < n/(n**0.5) = n**0.5 < f`, a contradiction.</sup>

Comment: The approach may be nice, but the result is just plain wrong. The numbers should be `[1, 42, 246, 287, 728]`, just as they appear in the question. The issue comes from doubling the "middle" term when checked number is a square number itself (so `n == q/n`).

Comment: @tevemader, "just plain wrong"? Not, "you forgot..."? :-) In any event, thanks for pointing out the error. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Ruby but the problem lies with the algorithm used in finding the divisors of a number (which is not specific to the language used, i.e. Ruby in this case).

```
r = (m..n).to_a.map { |z| (1..z).select { |x| z % x == 0} }
```

To find the divisors of an integer `n` you are dividing `n` by all positive integers unto `n - 1` which means the loop runs `n - 1` times. However, it is enough to divide upto `sort(n)` to calculate the divisors. In pseudocode this looks like below:

```
for i = 1 to i <= sqrt(n)
    r = n % i
    if r == 0 then
        i is a divisor
        if n / i != i then
            n / i is another divisor
```

For example:

```
sqrt_42 = 6.48074069840786
i = 1 => 1 and 42 are two divisors
i = 2 => 2 and 21
i = 3 => 3 and 14
i = 4 => no divisor
i = 5 => no divisor
i = 6 => 6 and 7
```

And thats all.

This will improve the performance a lot since now the loop runs only `sort(n)` times instead of `n - 1` times which is a big difference for large `n`.

Comment: Also, as Cary noted in his answer, finding one factor actually often gives you a second factor "almost" for free.

Comment: Thanks task! I completely forgot about using the square root function to simplify a way to obtain divisors.