# Python Code Optimization of 4-line program

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I currently have a working program as follows:

```
from math import sqrt
def list_squared(m, n):
    #sum of the squared divisors of a number
    def D(x):return sum([i**2 for i in range(1,x+1) if not x%i])
    #returns array of arrays containing each num and D(num) from m to n if D(num) is square 
    return [[i,D(i)] for i in range(m,n) if sqrt(D(i)).is_integer()]
```

However, this program does not execute fast enough for the server to count it as a working solution. I've never worked on optimizing code before and could use some help on how to go about making this execute faster.

The program is a solution for the problem below:

> Divisors of 42 are : 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 14, 21, 42. 
>   These divisors squared are: 1, 4, 9, 36, 49, 196, 441, 1764. 
>   The sum of the squared divisors is 2500 which is 50 * 50, a square!
>   Given two integers m, n (1 <= m <= n) we want to find all integers between m and n whose sum of squared divisors is itself a square. 42 is such a number.
>   The result will be an array of arrays, each subarray having two elements, first the number whose squared divisors is a square and then the sum of the squared divisors.

```
#Examples
list_squared(1, 250) --> [[1, 1], [42, 2500], [246, 84100]]
list_squared(42, 250) --> [[42, 2500], [246, 84100]]
```

Comment: `def D(x):return sum(i**2 for i in range(1,x+1) if not x%i)`, that is one

Comment: PEP-572 is trying to change this, but right now a regular for loop would be more suitable here than a list comprehension.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34891170/find-all-integers-between-m-and-n-whose-sum-of-squared-divisors-is-itself-a-squa

Comment: There are two things (or more) that from a programming perspective you can do. First off, you can use a *generator expression* instead of a list comprehension within `sum`. Secondly, instead of calling the `D` function at each iteration with same argument you can use *memoization* to cache previously called functions with same arguments. The `functools`  module has a `lru_cache` for this purpose which has its pros and cons that you can check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) for more details.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Feel free to recommend the OP post on CR but in the future, please don't use Code Review as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *too broad*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: @SamOnela. Thanks for the link to that post. It seems pretty authoritative.

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't be the best answer to this question, but it's how I would go about optimizing this specific code.  This is more of a start than a final results,  but.. well... here it goes:

```
import time
from math import sqrt


ITERATIONS = 10000


def timer(func, *args, **kwargs):
    start = time.time()
    for _ in range(ITERATIONS):
        func(*args)
    print("%s at %s iterations took %s" % (func.__name__, ITERATIONS, time.time() - start))


def list_squared(m, n):
    # base function
    #sum of the squared divisors of a number
    def D(x):return sum([i**2 for i in range(1, x+1) if not x % i])
    #returns array of arrays containing each num and D(num) from m to n if D(num) is square
    return [[i, D(i)] for i in range(m, n) if sqrt(D(i)).is_integer()]


def D(x):
    return sum([i**2 for i in range(1, x + 1) if not x % i])


def list_squared_opt1(m, n):
    # reduce the amount of function overhead
    ret_list = list()
    for i in range(m, n):
        tmp = D(i)
        if sqrt(tmp).is_integer():
            ret_list.append([i, tmp])
    return ret_list


def list_squared_opt2(m, n):
    # further reduce the amount of function overhead
    ret_list = list()
    for i in range(m, n):
        tmp = sum([x**2 for x in range(1, i + 1) if not i % x])
        if sqrt(tmp).is_integer():
            ret_list.append([i, tmp])
    return ret_list


def list_squared_opt3(m, n):
    # Improve the math overhead to not check for impossible divisors
    ret_list = list()
    for i in range(m, n):
        tmp = sum([x ** 2 for x in range(1, int(i / 2 + 1)) if not i % x]) + i ** 2
        if sqrt(tmp).is_integer():
            ret_list.append([i, tmp])
    return ret_list

def list_squared_opt4(m, n):
# Further reduce function overhead
ret_list = list()
for i in range(m, n):
    a = int()
    for x in range(1, int(i / 2 + 1)):
        if not i % x:
            a += x ** 2
    a += i ** 2
    if sqrt(a).is_integer():
        ret_list.append([i, a])
return ret_list

print("Timing results for various functions, then executing them once to validate the results")
timer(list_squared, 42, 250)
print("Results are: %s" % list_squared(42, 250))
timer(list_squared_opt1, 42, 250)
print("Results are: %s" % list_squared_opt1(42, 250))
timer(list_squared_opt2, 42, 250)
print("Results are: %s" % list_squared_opt2(42, 250))
timer(list_squared_opt3, 42, 250)
print("Results are: %s" % list_squared_opt3(42, 250))
timer(list_squared_opt4, 42, 250)
print("Results are: %s" % list_squared_opt4(42, 250))
```

This outputs:

```
/usr/test/venv/bin/python /usr/test/blah.py
Timing results for various functions, then executing them once to validate the results
list_squared at 10000 iterations took 16.172016859054565
Results are: [[42, 2500], [246, 84100]]
list_squared_opt1 at 10000 iterations took 15.923789834976196
Results are: [[42, 2500], [246, 84100]]
list_squared_opt2 at 10000 iterations took 15.620330572128296
Results are: [[42, 2500], [246, 84100]]
list_squared_opt3 at 10000 iterations took 11.640689611434937
Results are: [[42, 2500], [246, 84100]]
list_squared_opt4 at 10000 iterations took 10.224685668945312
Results are: [[42, 2500], [246, 84100]]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Now for some explanation.  What I'm trying to display is a means of taking an iterative approach to code optimization.  In the first couple if modified functions we test something fairly simple,  modifying the code structure to limit the number of function calls, which in theory should save some time, though it appears to be negligible. So far the biggest effect as been optimizing the math in the function.  There are more things I would try:

- Use treading or multiprocessing to take better account of the available system resources (this is a single threaded app currently)
- Look for more efficient ways to find the divisors (perhaps numpy or some underlying C lib)
- Further optimizing the math... I didn't spend a lot of time on that, but it still seems like it should be possible
- Testing quicker data structures, perhaps tuples in the returned list would be quicker (depending on the number of results)  etc

Hope this helps...