# How can I optimize this Ruby code to run faster?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, optimization

In the range from m..n, looking to get the numbers whose squared sum of divisors is a perfect square. Return the number and the perfect square in an array. This is a codewars challenge and only failing due to time out, the tests themselves pass. Ex. Divisors of 42 are : 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 14, 21, 42. These divisors squared are: 1, 4, 9, 36, 49, 196, 441, 1764. The sum of the squared divisors is 2500 which is 50 * 50, a square. So I'd return [42, 2500].

```
def list_squared(m, n)
  divisors = []
  matches = []

  # array of divisors for each num in the range
  (m..n).each do |num|
    divisors.push((1..num).select { |n| num % n == 0 })
  end

  # sum the squares of each array and push last element of the set, and perfect square to matches array
  divisors.each do |sets|
    sum = 0
    sets.each { |num| sum+=num**2 }
    if Math.sqrt(sum)%1 == 0
      matches.push([sets[-1],sum])
    end
  end
  return matches
end
```

Comment: ___Is this a possible duplicate for___ [Find all integers between m and n whose sum of squared divisors is itself a square](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34891170/5698098)?

Comment: Also the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) site may be better suited for this kind of question. There you'll find (again) [Find all integers between m and n whose sum of squared divisors is itself a square](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/117324/92689).

Comment: Your question title is pretty generic which makes it hard to find this Q/A later on. Try to make your title more descriptive. Have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all integers between m and n whose sum of squared divisors is itself a square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34891170/find-all-integers-between-m-and-n-whose-sum-of-squared-divisors-is-itself-a-squa)

Comment: Yes, I was able to use the solution below. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When finding factors, you don't need to check every number from 1 to num.
 
Instead, check every number from 1 to sqrt(num).
 
If you find a divisor, add the divisor and num/divisor.
 
Lastly check if the number is a perfect square.
 
If it is, add the square root

for 42:
 
sqrt(42) is ~6.48 
 
so you only need to do 7 checks instead of 42

n = 1 true 
 
so you add 1 and 42/1 = 42 
 
n = 2 true 
 
so you add 2 and 42/2 = 21 
 
n = 3 true 
 
so you add 3 and 42/3 = 14 
 
n = 4 false 
 
n = 5 false 
 
n = 6 true 
 
so you add 6 and 42/6 = 7

now n is 7
 
so you check if n*n is num
 
7*7 isn't 42
 
and you are done.

I'm not very proficient in Ruby, but it might look something like this

```
def factors(num)
  divisors = []
  n = 1
  while n*n < num
    if num % n == 0
      divisors << n
      divisors << num/n
    end
    n += 1
  end
  if n*n == num
    divisors << n
  end
  divisors
end
```

As for the square root of the squares of the divisors, you could calculate the squares when you're adding the divisors.

It might look something like this

```
def is_perfect_square(num)
  square_of_divisors = 0
  n = 1
  while n*n < num
    if num % n == 0
      square_of_divisors += n**2 + (num/n)**2
    end
    n += 1
  end
  if n*n == num
    square_of_divisors += n**2
  end
  sqrt_divisors = Math.sqrt(square_of_divisors)
  sqrt_divisors == sqrt_divisors.to_i
end
```

So, my modified version of your code is

```
def list_squared(m, n)
  matches = []

  (m..n).each do |num|
    square_of_divisors = 0

    k = 1
    while k*k < num
      if num % k == 0
        square_of_divisors += k**2 + (num/k)**2
      end
      k += 1
    end
    if k*k == num
      square_of_divisors += k**2
    end

    sqrt_divisors = Math.sqrt(square_of_divisors)
    if sqrt_divisors == sqrt_divisors.to_i
      matches << ([num, square_of_divisors.to_i])
    end
  end

  matches
end
```

Again, this might not be the most "Ruby" way of doing it, so modify it to your liking.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to format ALL your text correctly. That helps others understand what your intent is, and it saves us the time from trying to decipher it and turn it into something more understandable to others. "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)"
and "[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/)" explain why it's important.

Comment: @theTinMan thank you. Was there anything in particular that was hard to decipher?