# How to optimize this code by using another method besides .each (in Ruby)?

Tags: ruby

**Instructions (from `Codewars`):** 
https://www.codewars.com/kata/55aa075506463dac6600010d/train/ruby 
`1, 246, 2, 123, 3, 82, 6, 41` are the divisors of number `246`. Squaring these divisors we get: `1, 60516, 4, 15129, 9, 6724, 36, 1681`. The sum of these squares is `84100` which is `290 * 290`.

Task:
Find all integers between m and n (`m` and `n` integers such as `1 <= m <= n`) such that the sum of their squared divisors is itself a square.

We will return an array of subarrays or of tuples (in `C` an array of `Pair`) or a string. The subarrays (or `tuples` or `Pairs`) will have two elements: first the number the squared divisors of which is a square and then the sum of the squared divisors.

Example:

```
list_squared(1, 250) --> [[1, 1], [42, 2500], [246, 84100]]
list_squared(42, 250) --> [[42, 2500], [246, 84100]]
```

The form of the examples may change according to the language, see `"Sample Tests"`.

**My Attempt:**

```rb
def list_squared(m, n)
  arr = []
  
  (m..n).each do |t|
    sum = (1..t).select {|n| t % n == 0}.map! {|n| n**2}.sum
  
    if Math.sqrt(sum) % 1 == 0 then arr.push([t, sum]) end
  end
    
  arr
end
```

The code is successful, as in it passes all test, but always times out at `12000 ms`.

How could I optimize my code to make it run faster?

Comment: I expect this is more a math problem than a coding problem. One needs to exploit number theory to find a more efficient way of computing the sum of squared divisors of a positive integer (or possibly determining directly if that sum is a square, meaning that the powers of each of its prime factors is a multiple of 2). See, for example, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166501/delta-2n-the-sum-of-the-squares-of-the-positive-divisors-of-n). If you are working on this problem as a way of sharpening your Ruby coding skills I suggest you move on.

Comment: I just found that your question was asked here [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34891170/find-all-integers-between-m-and-n-whose-sum-of-squared-divisors-is-itself-a-squa). I'm not convinced, however, that any of the answers (one of which was authored by yours truly, though I have no recollection of it) provided the most efficient solution.

Comment: Tip: Don't use `then` on your `if` statements. Just split that up onto multiple lines, make it readable.

Comment: Pretty sure a little caching could help a ton here.

Comment: `isqrt =Integer.sqrt(n); isqrt*isqrt == n` is the fastest way I know to determine if a number is square.

Comment: @steenslag, I was curious how much faster that test was to `Prime.prime_division(n).all? { |_,p| p.even? }`. For `n = 723*723` and `n = 723*723+1` it is more than 100 times as fast (using fruity to test), and the ratio natually increases with `n`.